# Set Value with current User Email

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save data with the current user email as the child but when I start my project the application crash with this error message: terminating with uncaught exception of type `NSException`

```
let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
let SavedProduct : [String: Any] = ["email": email, "ImageURL": FImage1[picturenumber]]
Database.database().reference().child("SavedWoman").child(email!).setValue(SavedProduct)
```

Comment: You should post the entire error message.

Comment: It is the full error message!

Comment: looks like email == nil and you force unwrapping it? why don't you use and if let email = auth....email {}

Comment: Please. Do not use email addresses as node keys. You will have to encode and decode them as keys cannot contain periods (and some other characters). More importantly email addresses change and if that happens every place in your entire database that references that node will have to be read in, deleted and written back out with the new email. You are WAY better off creating your keys with .childByAutoId and keeping the email address as a child node.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an email address as the key of a Firebase Database node, as those keys can't contain periods, while each email address contains at least one of those.

The common solution is to encode the email address in some way. The simplest encoding is to replace the `.` with a `,`, which **is** allowed in Firebase keys, and conveniently can't occur in an email address.

So `jan2409@someaddress.com` would become `jan2409@someaddress,com`.